# Stuck on multiplication table in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming. I was trying to write a program that accepts an integer from user and displays its multiplication table up to 10 multiples. 
This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
        int number;
        int count = 1;
        int sum;

        printf("Enter a number to display its table: ");
        scanf(" %i ", &number);

        while (count <=10)
                {
                    sum = number * count;
                    printf("%i x %i = %i\n", number, count, sum);
                    count += 1;
                }
return 0;
}
```

Compilation successfully completes, but when I execute the output file, nothing happens, the terminal is stuck at nothing, i've to press ctrl+c to get out..

[image: My output]

Comment: `scanf()` is one of the most avoided functions in C. Have you tried it without whitespaces?

Comment: I think for line-oriented input, [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) with [`atoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi)  would probably be a less error-prone way to go.

Comment: As a general rule, avoid posting pictures of text in the question. Always better to copy the raw text if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the spaces used in your scanf command.

If you replace that with

```
scanf("%i", &number);
```

you get an instant response.

Answer (score 7):

With your `scanf` format `" %i "`, the `scanf` function will read (and skip) possible leading spaces because of your leading space in the format.

Then it will read the integer.

Then, due to the trailing space, it will read and discard space until it find a *non-space* input.

Since there's no non-space input afterward, then `scanf` will block until you give some non-space input.

Solve simply by not having any spaces in the format. Or by entering some extra dummy input (followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

The problem resides with the scanf.

Just replace

```
scanf(" %i ", &number);
```

with:

```
scanf("%i", &number);
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
        int number;
        int count = 1;
        int sum;

        printf("Enter a number to display its table: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);  

        while (count <=10){
             sum = number * count;
             printf("%d * %d = %d\n", number, count, sum);
             count += 1;
        }
return 0;
}
```

---

*Note: You can use both `%d` or `%i` where `%d` specifies signed decimal integer while `%i` specifies integer.*

**Problem:** The problem of your code was using a whitespace before `%i`.

*Wrong:*

```
scanf(" %i ", &number); //Wrong
```

*Right:*

```
scanf("%i", &number); //Right.
```